# Rendering a Scene onto a native OpenGL buffer?

Tags: java, c, opengl, javafx, javafx-8

What would be the best way to render a Scene onto a native OpenGL buffer? The "solution" that comes to mind is to snapshot the scene, send over the pixels from PixelReader.getArgb and then render this. But creating and rendering a new snapshot at every smallest change of the UI seems like a very slow approach.

Comment: What is a "native OpenGL buffer?"

Comment: One running natively outside the JVM. Most likely I'll write to it using the glBitmap function. (Unless of course there's a way to have JavaFX render to the OpenGL buffer, but I doubt that)

Comment: @DanielZiltener have you checked http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ ? This has nothing to do with javafx itself ;)

Comment: Under certain conditions, JavaFx renders using OpenGL. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/architecture/jfxpub-architecture.htm.